# Impulse force on a flexible object such as rope and string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, integration

Can I calculate the impulse force on an object that is flexible by using Riemann’s Sum? For example, when a rope is released vertically and I want to calculate the force that the ground does at various moments during the fall such as when the lower end of the rope meets the ground or at the end when the upper end of the rope touches the ground.

I have tried to calculate using calculus, momentum and integration: I separated the rope in to tiny pieces ($\delta m$) and calculate the impulse force of every pieces (Note that $m$ is the rope mass and $t$ is the time that starts counting when the lower end meets the ground)
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n F_i(t) \delta t = \lim_ {a\to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^a \Delta v \delta m \\ \int_0^t F(t) \text{d}t = m\int_0^{1} (gt)v \text{d}v$$
as $\Delta v$ starts from 0 and become $gt$ when you calculate the difference of velocity on the upper end. So
$$\int_0^t F(t) \text{d}t = \frac {mgt}{2}$$
Then
$$F(t) = \frac {mg}{2}$$

I think the results is very weird since the force is constant and even less than $mg$ itself. So I believe I must have done something wrong or missed some concepts. Can you please tell me at which step that I am wrong and/or are there other ways to calculate situations like this?